# How to convert from ZZ to ZZ_p in Number Theory Library?

Tags: c++, ntl

Using [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/), I have to evaluate a polynomial in some point and I have found eval function: `void eval(ZZ_p& b, const ZZ_pX& f, const ZZ_p& a)`, but further in my program I have to use b as an exponent. The power function is like this: `void power(ZZ_p& x, const ZZ_p& a, const ZZ& e)`.

Is there a way to convert from ZZ to ZZ_p?

Comment: Problem solved: conv(ZZ dst, ZZ_p src). :)

Comment: According to http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-ex4.html you might also use `ZZ p; cin >> p; ZZ_p::init(p);ZZ_pX f; cin >> f;`

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is better to have `ZZ_p` and use `rep`:

```
ZZ_p p;
power(x, a, rep(p));
```

for the read-only `const ZZ&` representation of it. This way you avoid unnecessary `ZZ -> ZZ_p` parsing.